# Bayes theorem probability doesn't make sense

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian-statistics

I try to use Bayes Theorem to calculate the probability of $P(A|B)$. I have $P(A)$ in column1, $P(B|A)$ in colmn2, $P(B)$ in column 3. I get the following:

[image]

my calculations were:

$$P(B/A) = 0.8\times A$$
$$P(B) = (Bx*0,55)+((1-Bx)*(0,55))$$
$$P(A/B) = (Ax*Bx)/Cx$$

The probability gets above 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is $Bx$, $Ax$, and $Cx$?

Comment: The columns a=column1, b column2, etc.. x indicates the element per row.

Comment: Then your data in the last two rows is obviously wrong! It's simply impossible for P(B | A) * P(A) > P(B)

Answer (score 3):

Well, then your data is clearly wrong!!

Bayes Theorem or not, you simply **cannot** have
$$P\left(B\,|\,A \right) \times P\left(A\right) > P\left(B\right) $$
but this "impossibility" is *exactly* what happens in your last two rows!!

Comment: Perfect answer. To (slightly) expand your argument the inequality is impossible by monotonicity of probability since $P(A \cap B) = P(B \mid A) P(A)$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your data! For example, the last row shows that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(B|A) = 0.8$. If $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$ means $A$ is equivalent to all possiblities of event world. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(B|A)$ couldn't be anything except 1.

Comment: That explains why things go wrong for the last row but not why they go wrong in the second to last row, rtight?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @OmG that the table is wrong.
However, $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)$ must be equal to $\mathbb{P}(B)$ and not $1$.

**Intuitively:** as @OmG said, $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ means that under $\mathbb{P}$ the event $A$ is not informative therefore you will not update the probability of $B$ after conditioning on $A$ and thus $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)$ must be equal to $\mathbb{P}(B)$.

**Formally:** by definition of the conditional probability of an event,
$$\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(B \cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\mathbb{P}(B),$$
since $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$.
Thus, $\mathbb{P}(B \cap A)=\mathbb{P}(B)$.
It contradicts your table.